# What is the best JavaScript solution to limit the length of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a canonical solution for limiting the number of characters that someone can enter into a textarea?

I have server side validation of course, but would like to improve the user experience by adding client side code to simulate the experience you get with maxlength on an input[type="text"] so that users never see the "your input is too long" error message if they have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My non-technical $0.02

Do what SO does in their comment fields, provide feedback as to what the user's character length remaining is and allow them to go past the maximum, but not submit > 300 characters.  Here's why:

Allowing users to go over the maximum number of characters allows them to complete an idea.  They can then go back and edit that idea.  There's nothing worse than being at the end of a sentence and being unable to complete it.

Providing feedback to character length keeps people from having to guess what their length is at.

Comment: It was a hard decision to give you a +1 since I have my own answer here :-) But I find your reasons quite valueable for the topic.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it this way:

```
$ ('#textarea-id').bind (
  'change input keyup keydown keypress mouseup mousedown cut copy paste',
  function () { return ($(this).val().length <= maxlength) }
)
```

So many bingings just to be *completely* sure :-)

Comment: Isn't working. When char limit is reached it is not possible to change it anymore. Not even delete.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an onchange event to the textarea. There you can check if the value's larger than the appropriate or not. Example with jQuery:

```
$("#textarea-id").change(function (){
  var text = $(this).val();
  if( text.length > MAX ){
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Onchange will only fire after you leave (blur) the textarea.

Comment: That aborts the entire change even if it is 1 character too long?

Comment: You can't abort a change event, anyway.

Comment: ah the obligatory jquery response

Answer (score 1):

This will do it...

```
function textareaMaxLen(event) {
  var max = parseInt(this.attr("maxlength"), 10);
  if(this.value.length >= max)
    this.value = this.value.substr(0, max);
}

$("textarea").keyup(textareaMaxLen).blur(textareaMaxLen);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this in the past:

```
<textarea onkeyup="checkLength(this);"></textarea>
```

Then implement this function:

```
function checkLength(control) {
            if (control.value.length > 5) {
                control.value = control.value.substr(0, 5);
            }
        }
```

It's a pretty basic example fixing the length to 5, but hopefully gives you the idea!

Comment: I won't give you a -1, but I don't think "keyup" is sufficient.  You can paste text in without a keyboard event, for example.

Comment: It's better to use onchange than onkeyup because the change event will capture things like pasted text and keys held down. Think of it this way, you're interested in the data, not what how the user is manipulating it

Comment: Good point - it'll still work with keyup for ctrl-V but not for right-click and Paste. onchange isn't nice either though as it only fires when the user exits the box, meaning they'd end up typing loads only to see it cleared back to 5 characters (or whatever the limit is).